# Intentionally bad HTTP clients for testing

Tags: http, testing, integration-testing, httpserver

What are good "bad HTTP client"-s I can use to test your HTTP servers?

For instance, there are servers like

1. https://httpbin.org/
2. https://badssl.com/

which allow you to test client against different, sometimes intentionally bad, behavior.

I seek for HTTP client utility for testing HTTP servers. It may send wrong Content-Length or close connection in the middle of request, or do other bad things which robust HTTP server should handle.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/tamper-data-for-ff-quantum/) (for Firefox). I see that there is an equivalent for Chrome - [Tamper Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tamper-chrome-extension/hifhgpdkfodlpnlmlnmhchnkepplebkb?hl=en).

These plugins allow you to edit the HTTP request prior to sending it to the server. This way you can do a number of test cases e.g.:

- Changing the content length or type
- Bypassing the client-side field validation

These are great for manual, exploratory testing.